# The time scale of charge accumulation or polarization by applied electric fields

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, dielectric, metals

When electric fields are applied to metal or dielectric, as a response, the charge accumulation (in metals) or the polarization (in dielectrics) is induced. I wonder how fast the response is complete. In other words, if we have to construct an experiment to measure the charge accumulation or the polarization, how should far the measurement time be away from the time of the electric fields turning on in typical metals or dielectrics.